# Pivot query on a very large table

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I have a SQL Server table:
Some key columns, period, value

Period can go from 1 to about 50. I need to get the result in the following format:

Key columns, period1value, period2value, ...

It looks like a simple pivot query (not even an aggregation) but the problem is that the table has 10 million rows so the pivot will take forever. 
What would be the best solution?

I will be reading the table in C#, so one possibility it to do
Pivot if there but I am not sure it will be faster.

Answer (score 0):

so the problem is not pivot, but performance; why not try to add an index on you Period column and then pivot

Comment: Do you mean an index on "key columns+Period"? Does it matter than periods are always sequential in the table?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Large amount of data Pivoting using SSAS will be Quick as compare to SQL Pivot